# Adding Custom Thymeleaf Template Resolver to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

By Default, Spring Boot Application searches thymeleaf templates under ***classpath://templates***

How do we add one more resolver For E.g, We need to search templates from local directory like ***"c:\MyTemplates"*** using [FileTemplateResolver](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/FileTemplateResolver.html) ?

Comment: I didn't know Spring boot searches for thymeleaf templates only in templates folder. I had mine in static folder and it wasn't resolving. +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add more template resolvers on the [TemplateEngine](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html) either by invoking the [setTemplateResolvers](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html#setTemplateResolvers(java.util.Set)) method or by invoking the [addTemplateResolver](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html#addTemplateResolver(org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver)) method with your `FileTemplateResolver`.

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafExtension {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @PostConstruct
    public void extension() {
        FileTemplateResolver resolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("D:\\templates\\");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(templateEngine.getTemplateResolvers().size());
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Template repository implementation does not seem to honor the Order property: at line 203 there is no sorting on order property: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/TemplateRepository.java/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414055/spring-boot-multiple-template-location - this article helped me.

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement of the previous answer:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    public ThymeleafConfig(TemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new StringTemplateResolver());
    }
}
```