# Spring Boot - multiple template location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want Spring look for templates in different locations, not only in `src/main/resource/templates/`.

Here what I have

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig{

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @PostConstruct
    public void clientTemplate(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("static/client");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(templateEngine.getTemplateResolvers().size());
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

But when I try to access a existing template *index.html* in `/src/main/resources/static/client`, I've got:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ApplicationContext has not been initialized in resource resolver. TemplateResolver or ResourceResolver might not have been correctly configured by the Spring Application Context.
at org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.resourceresolver.SpringResourceResourceResolver.getResourceAsStream(SpringResourceResourceResolver.java:81)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:221)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Non-Spring managed SpringResourceTemplateResolver

With your current setup, you are creating an instance of `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`, **NOT** in a `@Bean` method. Thus, it doesn't get picked up by spring and you need to provide the `ApplicationContext` ([example](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html)):

```
SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
```

Notice the `resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);`

---

### 2. Spring managed SpringResourceTemplateResolver

You are probably seeing examples which don't need do that, but they are most certainly creating the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` instance in a `@Bean` method. Spring picks it up and sets the application context for you ([example](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2016/05/thymeleaf-3-get-started-quickly-with.html)):

```
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work, as SpringResourceTemplateResolver doesn't pass the application content to the SpringResourceResourceResolver (I suppose it's a ThymeLeaf bug). Option 2 did work just fine.

Comment: @BerthierLemieux I encountered this issue and is possibly and issue with 2.X versions. 3.X doesn't seem to have this issue. I had to use 2.X versions so I made my own version of SpringResourceTemplateResolver that allows the application context to be set manually.

Answer (score 3):

ThymeLeaf trips if the template resolver is not defined as a @Bean. You can replace your WebConfig class with this one.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig{
    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("static/client");
        // For Spring Boot
        // resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    } 
}
```

The new template will be picked up and added to the list of template resolvers, effectively doing the same operations as "templateEngine.addTemplateResolver()" would do.