# Java Spring - Can't save image to static folder

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, thymeleaf

I want to save image to `resources/static/photos` file, but Java/Kotlin can't find it. It finds `project/photos` well though.

This is a code, in Kotlin, but I don't think it matters

```
    override fun saveImage(imageFile: MultipartFile, id: String) {
        val bytes = imageFile.bytes

        val path = Paths.get(
            "$imagesFolderPath$id.${imageFile.originalFilename.substringAfter('.')}")
        Files.write(path, bytes)
    }
```

I need this to be saved to `resources/static/photos` to be able to access it from thymeleaf.

Thanks.

Comment: At runtime, the `resources` folder is read-only. You can't save files there, they must be saves externally to the source files.

Comment: Even if you get this to work, it will only work while you're developing. Once you package your application as an archive (jar / war / whatever) you can't add new files to your classpath like this.
You should rather look for an alternative template resolver.

Comment: The thing is `thymeleaf` can't see anything other than that resources, `java` can't see those resources. How can I solve this?

Comment: By adding another template resolver. By default, theres one template resolver attached to thymeleaf, which only looks into the `resources`. But you can add as many alternative template resolvers, which can look for templates whereever you want them to.

EDIT: You most likely want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156153/adding-custom-thymeleaf-template-resolver-to-spring-boot

Comment: You don't need an additional template resolver to load images. Save images somewhere on the file system (not inside the jar/war) then have a controller which serves them again.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, @M.Deinum is right. I thought you tried to upload templates, not images. As M.Deinum said, you can save the images on whatever storage you want, you just have to make sure there's a controller that is able to access and deliver those images via an endpoint in your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum `(not inside the jar/war)` you mean anywhere other than the project folders?

Comment: Anything outside the classpath. Also at runtime there are no project folders.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't get what u said, can you elaborate? I want to keep my links relative so it runs on another computer as well. I don't want to put files somewhere on the desktop, that's how I got your comment.

Comment: The project folder doesn't exist anymore after packaging. The normal way to handle this is to let the path be configurable (for example, by a program argument), create a new folder in the working directory or use an external system that is responsible for persistence (e.g. amazon s3)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get the terms you use. Can you provide an example? I think this is the only way I can understand. As I understand, working directory would be somewhere in the project, but `thymeleaf` can't see it, I don't think I understand it correctly.

Comment: The external links aren't tied to physical locations. Add a resource for the link to the image which knows where to retrieve it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you may be able to save files inside your projects directory during the development phase, but that won't be possible as soon as you export your project as an application package (a `.jar`-application, `.war`-archive etc), because at that point, everything that previously was an actual directory on your file-system is now a single file.

Here's an example how you could implement this by saving the images in a configurable folder:

I never wrote a line of code in Kotlin. I hope this example helps you even if it is in Java.

This is an example controller that accepts images to be uploaded on a `POST` endpoint and being downloaded on a `GET` endpoint:

```java
package example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.PathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final Path imageStorageDir;

    /*
    The target path can be configured in the application.properties / application.yml or using the parameter -Dimage-storage.dir=/some/path/
     */
    @Autowired
    public MyController(@Value("${image-storage-dir}") Path imageStorageDir) {
        this.imageStorageDir = imageStorageDir;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void ensureDirectoryExists() throws IOException {
        if (!Files.exists(this.imageStorageDir)) {
            Files.createDirectories(this.imageStorageDir);
        }
    }

    /*
    This enables you to perform POST requests against the "/image/YourID" path
    It returns the name this image can be referenced on later
     */
    @PostMapping(value = "/image/{id}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String uploadImage(@RequestBody MultipartFile imageFile, @PathVariable("id") String id) throws IOException {
        final String fileExtension = Optional.ofNullable(imageFile.getOriginalFilename())
                .flatMap(MyController::getFileExtension)
                .orElse("");

        final String targetFileName = id + "." + fileExtension;
        final Path targetPath = this.imageStorageDir.resolve(targetFileName);

        try (InputStream in = imageFile.getInputStream()) {
            try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(targetPath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {
                in.transferTo(out);
            }
        }

        return targetFileName;
    }

    /*
    This enables you to download previously uploaded images
     */
    @GetMapping("/image/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadImage(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
        final Path targetPath = this.imageStorageDir.resolve(fileName);
        if (!Files.exists(targetPath)) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new PathResource(targetPath));
    }

    private static Optional<String> getFileExtension(String fileName) {
        final int indexOfLastDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (indexOfLastDot == -1) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else {
            return Optional.of(fileName.substring(indexOfLastDot + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say you uploaded am image with the file-ending `.png` and the id `HelloWorld`, you could then access the image using the url:
`http://localhost:8080/image/HelloWorld.png`

Using this URL you can also reference the image in any of your thymeleaf templates:

`<img th:src="@{/image/HelloWorld.png}"></img>`

Comment: So you store the image file outside the package file (jar, war, etc.) right? Is this structure below is correct?
- projects/
   - web.war
   - images/