# Using templates from external sources outside the jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy, thymeleaf

I'm trying to access a file outside the jar in the file system from inside my applications.properties file. I created a mail configuration class with prefix mail.sink-service whose properties I'm trying to set. It can't seem to find the template. This is what I've been trying so far:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:./dataflow/templates/
mail.sink-service.template-location=classpath:./dataflow/templates/newnotice
mail.sink-service.source-base-name=classpath:./dataflow/templates/
```

I've also tried using file like this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./dataflow/templates/
mail.sink-service.template-location=file:./dataflow/templates/newnotice
mail.sink-service.source-base-name=file:./dataflow/templates/
```

and I've tried both with just this format:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./templates/
mail.sink-service.template-location=file:./templates/newnotice
mail.sink-service.source-base-name=file:./templates/
```

I've also tried using the absolute path but I get the same issue.

This is what my file structure looks like:

[image: file structure]

Comment: Possible duplicate: See [Adding Custom Thymeleaf Template Resolver to Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156153/adding-custom-thymeleaf-template-resolver-to-spring-boot) for an example of how to use a different type of [template resolver](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#template-resolvers).

Comment: I do have a template resolver defined as well

Comment: Understood - can you share how you are doing that?

Comment: My apologies. Seems like I had the wrong type for the resolver. I had a ClassLoaderTemplateResolver instead of a FileTemplateResolver as is shown in the question you linked to. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - glad you resolved it.

Comment: Just use `file:` prefix like so: `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./templates`